Tiles missing in export of A3 sized (scale 1:25,000) OpenTopoMap!
I'm trying to export a map (OpenTopoMap) of size 4960x3507px (300dpi, A3-format), but it doesn't seem to work. It does when setting the resolution to 100dpi.
Higher resolutions don't work; each try yields the same tiles missing. I tried increasing the network timeout, and retry settings, but still incomplete export. Even increasing the cache to 100MB didn't work either!
I'm using QGIS 3.10.4, and running out of options.
Anyone any idea how to tackle this issue?
